# Is there a difference in Async execution vs non-async execution in WebAPI ASP.NET Core controllers?

Tags: .net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a difference between calling a method of service with async/await:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SmthResponce> AddSmth([FromBody] SmthRequest smthRequest)
    {
        return await smthsService.AddSmthAsync(smthRequest);
    }
```

and without:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<SmthResponce> AddSmth([FromBody] SmthRequest smthRequest)
    {
        return smthsService.AddSmthAsync(smthRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Ask yourself this question:  How will I get the values from your two examples? Hint: var x = AddSmth("test"); y = x;

Comment: There are some subtle differences between the two: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html. How much these will affect you depends on the implementation of `AddSmthAsync`. However, I assume they typically shouldn't have any effect for Web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the callers perspective, there is no difference; however...

The first method (await) involves the creation of an additional Task, which will be completed when the inner Task completes.

The second method (returning the Task directly, when possible) is preferred.